# Undefined control sequence. (\end{tabularx}})

Tags: tables

I am a master's student working on the literature review of my thesis. As this is my first time working in LaTeX, I am having some difficulties in making the table containing an overview of existing research.

My current code of the table is given below:

```
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabularx}{18cm}{m{5.3cm}*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.6cm}}*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}}*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}}X}
            \toprule
            &  &  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Models}} & \\
            \cmidrule(1){4-8} 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\fontsize{12}{3}\selectfont Study}} & {\fontsize{12}{3}\selectfont Credit Scoring} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont IDCS} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont LR} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont RF} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont XGB} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont NN} & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont SVM}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont XAI}\\
            \midrule
            \cite{bahnsen2014example} & \checkmark   & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&\\
            \cite{bahnsen2015example}\footnotemark & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&&\\
            \cite{bahnsen2015ensemble} & \checkmark   & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&&\\
            \cite{hoppner2017profit} && \checkmark &&\checkmark&  &&& \\
            \cite{garrido2018robust}\footnotemark & \checkmark &&&&& \checkmark && \\
            \cite{iranmehr2019cost} & & \checkmark &&&&& \checkmark &\\
            \cite{ling2021cost} & & \checkmark &&&& \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{janssens2022b2boost} &  & \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{lima2022evaluation} &  & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark &\checkmark&&& \\
            \cite{hoppner2022instance} && \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{petrides2022cost} & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  &\checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vanderschueren2022instance} & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark && \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vanderschueren2022predict} & \checkmark   & \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vasquez2022hidden} && \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{zou2022business} && \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&& {\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont PDP \& FI}\\           
            \cite{james2023bi} & & \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{de2023robust} & & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&\\
            \cite{chen2024interpretable} & \checkmark &&&\checkmark& \checkmark &&&{\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont SHAP \& LIME}\\
            \midrule
            \textbf{This study} &\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&{\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont SHAP \& LIME}
    \end{tabularx}}
    \caption{Literature review IDCS classification in credit scoring}
    \label{tab_literature_review}
\end{table}
```

And corresponds to this table:

[image]

While the way in which I constructed it is probably not optimal, it visually matches what I would like it to represent. I keep getting the following error messages, however: [image]

I don't think it has something to do with my preamble, but in case I also need to share that, feel free to tell me!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: What is `\cmidrule(1){4-8}` supposed to do? As far as I remember, the argument in `()` corrensponds to trimming the line. You would usually use womething like `l`, `r`, `lr` , `l{1em}` or something similar.

Comment: the error is marked in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Never scale tables. Reduce the font instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,array,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize

% local command for simplicity
\newcommand{\X}{\checkmark}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X c *{6}{w{c}{2em}} >{\scriptsize}l @{}}
\toprule
Study &
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Credit \\ scoring \end{tabular}} &
  IDCS &
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Models} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{XAI} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-8} 
& & & LR & RF & XGB & NN & SVM & \\
\midrule
\cite{bahnsen2014example}              & \X & \X & \X &    &    &    &    & \\
\cite{bahnsen2015example}\footnotemark & \X & \X &    &    &    &    &    & \\
\cite{bahnsen2015ensemble}             & \X & \X &    & \X &    &    &    & \\
\cite{hoppner2017profit}               &    & \X &    & \X &    &    &    & \\
\cite{garrido2018robust}\footnotemark  & \X &    &    &    &    & \X &    & \\
\cite{iranmehr2019cost}                &    & \X &    &    &    &    & \X & \\
\cite{ling2021cost}                    &    & \X &    &    &    & \X &    & \\
\cite{janssens2022b2boost}             &    & \X &    &    & \X &    &    & \\
\cite{lima2022evaluation}              &    & \X & \X & \X & \X &    &    & \\
\cite{hoppner2022instance}             &    & \X & \X &    & \X &    &    & \\
\cite{petrides2022cost}                & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X &    & \\
\cite{vanderschueren2022instance}      & \X & \X & \X &    & \X & \X &    & \\
\cite{vanderschueren2022predict}       & \X & \X & \X &    & \X & \X &    & \\
\cite{vasquez2022hidden}               &    & \X &    &    & \X &    &    & \\
\cite{zou2022business}                 &    & \X &    &    & \X &    &    & PDP \& FI\\   
\cite{james2023bi}                     &    & \X & \X &    & \X &    &    & \\
\cite{de2023robust}                    &    & \X & \X &    &    &    &    & \\
\cite{chen2024interpretable}           & \X &    &    & \X & \X &    &    & SHAP \& LIME\\
\midrule
\textbf{This study}                    & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X & SHAP \& LIME \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Literature review IDCS classification in credit scoring}
\label{tab_literature_review}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be consistent in the headers: “Study”, “Credit scoring”, “Models” and “XAI” belong to the first line.

I used a local command to ease both input and readability of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Working with an approximate preamble and without the bibliography compiles fine - the error is marked in the `\cmidrule` synatax

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{dingbat}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
%   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabularx}{18cm}{m{5.3cm}*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.6cm}}*{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}}*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}}X}
            \toprule
            &  &  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Models}} & \\
            \cmidrule(l){4-8} %<----------------error over here it should be (l) not (1)
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\fontsize{12}{3}\selectfont Study}} 
                & {\fontsize{12}{3}\selectfont Credit Scoring} 
                    & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont IDCS} 
                        & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont LR} 
                            & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont RF} 
                                & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont XGB} 
                                    & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont NN} 
                                        & {\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont SVM}
                                            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\fontsize{11}{3}\selectfont XAI}
                                            \\
            \midrule
            \cite{bahnsen2014example} & \checkmark   & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&\\
            \cite{bahnsen2015example}\footnotemark & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&&\\
            \cite{bahnsen2015ensemble} & \checkmark   & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&&\\
            \cite{hoppner2017profit} && \checkmark &&\checkmark&  &&& \\
            \cite{garrido2018robust}\footnotemark & \checkmark &&&&& \checkmark && \\
            \cite{iranmehr2019cost} & & \checkmark &&&&& \checkmark &\\
            \cite{ling2021cost} & & \checkmark &&&& \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{janssens2022b2boost} &  & \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{lima2022evaluation} &  & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark &\checkmark&&& \\
            \cite{hoppner2022instance} && \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{petrides2022cost} & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  &\checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vanderschueren2022instance} & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark && \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vanderschueren2022predict} & \checkmark   & \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark & \checkmark &&\\
            \cite{vasquez2022hidden} && \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{zou2022business} && \checkmark &&& \checkmark &&& {\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont PDP \& FI}\\           
            \cite{james2023bi} & & \checkmark & \checkmark && \checkmark &&&\\
            \cite{de2023robust} & & \checkmark & \checkmark &&&&&\\
            \cite{chen2024interpretable} & \checkmark &&&\checkmark& \checkmark &&&{\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont SHAP \& LIME}\\
            \midrule
            \textbf{This study} &\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&{\fontsize{10}{3}\selectfont SHAP \& LIME}
    \end{tabularx}
%}
    \caption{Literature review IDCS classification in credit scoring}
    \label{tab_literature_review}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I erroneously copied that line and misread the l for a 1. Should have known spending hours on it myself was not efficient :). Have a great rest of your Sunday!

Comment: welcome to `TeX`ing - if the answer met your requirement do upvote and accept the answer with a green tick mark